# Laravel - How to save api endpoint into database

Tags: laravel, api

I have this endpoint that is being displayed. But I have an API endpoint that I want to save into the database.

```
     public function apifeed(Request $request)
    {
        $array_content=[];
        
         $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.company.com/article/6spf2p?_fmt=xml&_rt=b&_fld=hl,img,bd&lnk=urn:perform:image&_lcl=en");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Important
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
           
             //$array = json_decode($result, true);
            
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }
              curl_close ($ch);
            $plainXML = self::mungXML($result);
        $arrayResult = json_decode(json_encode(SimpleXML_Load_String($plainXML, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)), true);
        $i=0;
        foreach($arrayResult['article'] as $value)
        {
        $newobj = new stdClass();
        $newobj->id = $value['@attributes']['id'];
        $newobj->headline = $value['headline'];
        $newobj->body = $value['body'];
        $newobj->image_header ='https://images.performgroup.com'.
        $value['links']['link'][0]['@attributes']['url'];
        $newobj->image_teaser ='https://images.performgroup.com'.
        $value['links']['link'][1]['@attributes']['url'];
        $newobj->image_mobile ='https://images.performgroup.com'.
        $value['links']['link'][2]['@attributes']['url'];
        $newobj->image_source = 'https://images.performgroup.com'.
        
        array_push($array_content,$newobj);
        
        $i++;
        }
        return $array_content;
    }
```

I want to save it into this table

> news_feeds

```
CREATE TABLE `news_feeds` (
  `id` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `headline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `news_body` text NOT NULL,
  `image_teaser` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `image_mobile` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `image_source` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Model is NewsFeed

How do I write a foreach statement after

> return $array_content

and save into the table

> news_feeds
>
> $newobj->id into id
>
> $newobj->id into headline
>
> $newobj->body into news body
>
> $newobj->image_teaser into image_teaser

and so on.

Comment: On which model you want to save the data

Comment: You're really close. $newobj = new NewsFeed();  then you assign the id, headline, body, and other fields just like you have written them out. Lastly, call $newobj->save(); . There's lots of best practices you should consider putting this into production, but gets the job done. Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts

Comment: model name is NewsFeed and the table name is news_feeds. I put the coulmns in the code

Comment: Then if headline exists it should not save. It should do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a `stdClass` or add your looped data to a new array to save records. You can save records using laravel eloquent models.

After your `curl` call, you can use your `NewsFeed` model class and the `::create()` method to create a new `newsfeed` record:

```
foreach($arrayResult['article'] as $value)
{
    if (NewsFeed::where('headline', $value['headline'])->exists()) {
        continue;
    }

    NewsFeed::create([
        'id'           => $value['@attributes']['id'],
        'headline'     => $value['headline'],
        'body'         => $value['body'],
        'image_header' => 'https://images.performgroup.com'.$value['links']['link'][0]['@attributes']['url'],
        'image_teaser' => 'https://images.performgroup.com'.$value['links']['link'][1]['@attributes']['url'],
        'image_mobile' => 'https://images.performgroup.com'.$value['links']['link'][2]['@attributes']['url'],
        'image_source' => 'https://images.performgroup.com'
    ]);
}
```

Here, we initially check if the `newsfeed` exists by checking if there are any with the same `headline` we are trying to save. If it exists, we skip it.

If no `newsfeed` with the `headline` exists, we then use the `::create()` method to create the new `NewsFeed`. This should create a new record.

**Note:** Your `image_source` link was not completed.

Comment: Also, to clear up your code (`curl` being the culprit) you can use packages such as [`guzzle`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) or [`zttp`](https://github.com/kitetail/zttp).